# Reduce Multiple Objects into One, with max value and count

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects like this:

```
    [
        {
            name: "aaa",
            mainName: "bbb",
            occurrences: 3,
            collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 09:03:02",
            status: "unfinished"
        },

        {
            name: "aaa",
            mainName: "bbb",
            occurrences: 2,
            collectTime: "14-OCT-2018 05:63:42",
            status: "unfinished"
        },

        {
            name: "aaa",
            mainName: "bbb",
            occurrences: 5,
            collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 10:56:35",
            status: "finished"
        },

        {
            name: "ccc",
            mainName: "ddd",
            occurrences: 7,
            collectTime: "11-OCT-2018 13:12:41",
            status: "finished"
        },

        {
            name: "ccc",
            mainName: "ddd",
            occurrences: 10,
            collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 09:03:02",
            status: "finished"
        },

        {
            name: "ccc",
            mainName: "ddd",
            occurrences: 4,
            collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 22:36:32",
            status: "unfinished"
        },
    ]
```

However, I can't seem to get an array that looks like this:

```
    [
        {
            name: "aaa",
            mainName: "bbb",
            occurrences: 5,  // highest occurrences value for the unique combination of name and mainName
            collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 10:56:35",  // collectTime corresponding to the highest occurrences
            finished: 1, // count of the status 
            unfinished: 2 // count of the status 
        },

        {
            name: "ccc",
            mainName: "ddd",
            occurrences: 10, // highest occurrences value for the unique combination of name and mainName
            collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 09:03:02",  // collectTime corresponding to the highest occurrences
            finished: 2, // count of the status 
            unfinished: 1 // count of the status 
        },

    ]
```

I cannot figure out how exactly yo use Array.prototype.reduce() to get what I need. I have been able to make some progress, but can't quite get the exact result. Any guidance is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you please share your attempt so that we have a starting point to look at?

Comment: You should post what you have tried along with the above code. Edit the post and add your attempts so the community can help you correct what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to show your effort, but still, here is a working solution for you. Hopefully this will be an useful inspiration for your next projects:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: "aaa",
    mainName: "bbb",
    occurrences: 3,
    collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 09:03:02",
    status: "unfinished"
  },

  {
    name: "aaa",
    mainName: "bbb",
    occurrences: 2,
    collectTime: "14-OCT-2018 05:63:42",
    status: "unfinished"
  },

  {
    name: "aaa",
    mainName: "bbb",
    occurrences: 5,
    collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 10:56:35",
    status: "finished"
  },

  {
    name: "ccc",
    mainName: "ddd",
    occurrences: 7,
    collectTime: "11-OCT-2018 13:12:41",
    status: "finished"
  },

  {
    name: "ccc",
    mainName: "ddd",
    occurrences: 10,
    collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 09:03:02",
    status: "finished"
  },

  {
    name: "ccc",
    mainName: "ddd",
    occurrences: 4,
    collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 22:36:32",
    status: "unfinished"
  },
];

// Reduce the array
const res = arr.reduce((current, next) => {
  // Check whether the next item exists in the accumulator (current).
  const needle = current.find(i => i.name === next.name && i.mainName === next.mainName);
  // If it does...
  if (needle) {
    // increase the existing occurrences.
   needle.occurrences += +next.occurrences;
    // increase the status counter according to the next status.
    needle[next.status] += 1;
    // replace the collectTime if needed.
    needle.collectTime = next.occurrences > needle.highestOccurrences ? next.collectTime : needle.collectTime;
    // Keep track of the highest occurrence found so far.
    needle.highestOccurrences = next.occurrences > needle.highestOccurrences ? next.occurrences : needle.highestOccurrences;
  }
  // Otherwise..
  else {
    // Create a "finished" property, and set it to 0.
   next.finished = 0;
    // Create an "unfinished" property, and set it to 0.
    next.unfinished = 0;
    // Keep track of the highest occurrence for that item.
    next.highestOccurrences = next.occurrences;
    // Increase the status of that item accordingly.
    next[next.status] += 1;
    // Push this item to the accumulator.
   current.push(next);
  }
  return current;
}, []).map(function(item){
  // Once done, just remove the undesired / unneeded properties.. BEWARE: this is unnecessary.
  delete item.highestOccurrences;
  delete item.status;
  return item;
});
console.log(res);
```

Explanation is directly in the code.

As a side note, this will quite take care of performances already, using `find` instead of filter, and using a single reduce call.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array by taking a new object, if not one found with the same name or if found update the values, if necessary.

```js
var data = [{ name: "aaa", mainName: "bbb", occurrences: 3, collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 09:03:02", status: "unfinished" }, { name: "aaa", mainName: "bbb", occurrences: 2, collectTime: "14-OCT-2018 05:63:42", status: "unfinished" }, { name: "aaa", mainName: "bbb", occurrences: 5, collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 10:56:35", status: "finished" }, { name: "ccc", mainName: "ddd", occurrences: 7, collectTime: "11-OCT-2018 13:12:41", status: "finished" }, { name: "ccc", mainName: "ddd", occurrences: 10, collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 09:03:02", status: "finished" }, { name: "ccc", mainName: "ddd", occurrences: 4, collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 22:36:32", status: "unfinished" }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { name, mainName, occurrences, collectTime, status }) => {
        var temp = r.find((o) => o.name === name);
        if (temp) {
            if (occurrences > temp.occurrences) {
                temp.occurrences = occurrences;
                temp.collectTime = collectTime;
            }
            temp[status]++;
        } else {
            r.push({
                name,
                mainName,
                occurrences,
                collectTime,
                finished: +(status === 'finished'),
                unfinished: +(status === 'unfinished') });
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Interesting object destructuring as a second argument. Side question: may it be that the grouping should be done on both `name` and `mainName`? OP didn't specify.. however...

Comment: I'd still suggest to leverage object for `memo` in that case. Having `array.find` for every `reduce` iteration is suboptimal, as in the worst case, it'd need iterating till the end of growing array every time.

Answer (score 0):

`filter` will let you check to see if the combination of `name` and `mainName` already exists in your output set. Once you've established that, you can either push in the current entry if nothing exits matching that combination, or update the values based on whether or not the number of occurrences is higher.

```js
var input =     [
        {
            name: "aaa",
            mainName: "bbb",
            occurrences: 3,
            collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 09:03:02",
            status: "unfinished"
        },

        {
            name: "aaa",
            mainName: "bbb",
            occurrences: 2,
            collectTime: "14-OCT-2018 05:63:42",
            status: "unfinished"
        },

        {
            name: "aaa",
            mainName: "bbb",
            occurrences: 5,
            collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 10:56:35",
            status: "finished"
        },

        {
            name: "ccc",
            mainName: "ddd",
            occurrences: 7,
            collectTime: "11-OCT-2018 13:12:41",
            status: "finished"
        },

        {
            name: "ccc",
            mainName: "ddd",
            occurrences: 10,
            collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 09:03:02",
            status: "finished"
        },

        {
            name: "ccc",
            mainName: "ddd",
            occurrences: 4,
            collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 22:36:32",
            status: "unfinished"
        },
    ]
    
  const output = input.reduce((arr, obj) => {
    let existing = arr.filter(t => t.name == obj.name && t.mainName == obj.mainName)[0]

    if(existing){
      if(obj.occurrences > existing.occurrences) {
        Object.assign(existing, obj)
      }
      if(existing[obj.status]) {
        existing[obj.status] += 1
      } else {
        existing[obj.status] = 1
      }
      delete existing.status
    } else {
      obj[obj.status] = 1
      delete obj.status
      arr.push(obj)
    }
    
    return arr
  }, [])
  
  console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's - as you mentioned - classical `.reduce` problem, but in this case, your memo will have two entities. As you need to keep track of many different entities and aggregate them, I'd suggest to keep it as object of objects (thanks to that, accessing object will be faster). Using object of objects is cheaper from computational standpoint than either using another `map` of `find` or any other array operations.

Hence, your `memo` for reduce might look like that:

```
{
  'aaa': { 
     /* aaa content here */
  }, 
  'ccc': {
    /* ccc content here */
  }
}
```

Then, in the second go, you can standardise object (convert it to array). That way, you won't have to iterate over memo array every time in reduce.

I will assume that `name` and `mainName` always occur in the same way. If there are multiple combinations, you would have to adjust "summary" keys in order to have them unique (e.g. `` memo[`${element.name}_${element.mainName}`] `` - I used template strings for clarity);

1.Iterate over original array to get reduced "summary"

```
const result = myArray.reduce((memo, element) => {
  const uniqueKey = `${element[name]}_${element.mainName}`;
  // Initialize new memo key, if not available yet
  if (!memo[uniqueKey]) {
    memo[uniqueKey] = {
       name: element.name,
       mainName: element.mainName,
       collectTime: element.collectTime,
       occurrences: element.occurences,
       finished: element.status === 'finished' ? 1 : 0,
       unfinished: element.status === 'unfinished' ? 1 : 0,
    };
  }

  // I assume there are only 2 statuses here available
  if (element.status === 'finished') {
    memo[uniqueKey].finished = memo.finished + 1;
  } else {
    memo[uniqueKey].unfinished = memo.unfinished + 1;
  }

  // Increase occurences, if needed
  if (memo[uniqueKey].occurences < element.occurences) {
    memo[uniqueKey].occurences = element.occurences;
    memo[uniqueKey].collectTime = element.collectTime;
  }
}, {});
```

2.Convert memo to array. Notice that the memo is rather short, so conversion is cheap:

```
const newArray = Object.values(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce to an `Object` with the `name`-key as keys, use `Object.values` to retrieve an `Array` of the resulting values (objects). *Note*: in the snippet `getValues` only serves to start with the actual reducer code.

```js
const grouped = Object.values(
  getValues().reduce( (collection, value) => {
    const isFinished = value.status === "finished";
    const current = collection[value.name];
     if (!current) {
       collection[value.name] = { ...value,
        finished: +(isFinished), 
        unfinished: +(!isFinished) };
       delete collection[value.name].status;
     } else {
       collection[value.name] = { ...current,
        occurrences: Math.max(value.occurrences, current.occurrences),
        collectTime: new Date(current.collectTime) < new Date(value.collectTime) 
          ? value.collectTime 
          : current.collectTime ,
        finished:  +(isFinished) + current.finished,
        unfinished: +(!isFinished) + current.unfinished  };
     }
     return collection;
  }, {} )
);

console.log(grouped);

function getValues() {
  return [
    {
        name: "aaa",
        mainName: "bbb",
        occurrences: 3,
        collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 09:03:02",
        status: "unfinished"
    },

    {
        name: "aaa",
        mainName: "bbb",
        occurrences: 2,
        collectTime: "14-OCT-2018 05:63:42",
        status: "unfinished"
    },

    {
        name: "aaa",
        mainName: "bbb",
        occurrences: 5,
        collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 10:56:35",
        status: "finished"
    },

    {
        name: "ccc",
        mainName: "ddd",
        occurrences: 7,
        collectTime: "11-OCT-2018 13:12:41",
        status: "finished"
    },

    {
        name: "ccc",
        mainName: "ddd",
        occurrences: 10,
        collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 09:03:02",
        status: "finished"
    },

    {
        name: "ccc",
        mainName: "ddd",
        occurrences: 4,
        collectTime: "15-OCT-2018 22:36:32",
        status: "unfinished"
    },
  ];
}
```